# SKShapeNode defined in a function... how to get identifier

Tags: ios, swift, function, sprite-kit

I am facing the following problem.

I created a function in order to produce a custom button using SpriteKit:

```
func createButton(bx: CGFloat, by: CGFloat, bw: CGFloat, bh: CGFloat, yourText: String) {

let button = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: bx, y: by, width: bw, height: bh), cornerRadius: 5)
button.fillColor = UIColor.blue
( ... )
self.addChild(button)
```

I am calling the function like this:

```
self.createButton(bx: CGFloat(200), by: CGFloat(0), bw: CGFloat(130), bh: CGFloat(30), yourText: "testlabel")
```

How can I refer to this created object later on ?

E.G.:

I am trying to change the position of individual created elements using touch...

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
   if let touch = touches.first {
        let touchLoc = touch.location(in: self)
        let touchWhere = nodes(at: touchLoc)

        if !touchWhere.isEmpty {
            for node in touchWhere {
                if let node = node as? SKShapeNode {
                    if node == element1 {
                }
```

In earlier stages, I would have created an SkSpriteNode like this

```
element1 = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 30, height: 30), cornerRadius: 10)
    element1.fillColor = UIColor.red
        addChild(element1)
```

In the example above, I was able to refer to this particular element by calling the identifier "element1" where it says

```
if node == element1 {
```

But how can I realize the same thing when multiple elements are created using the function...

Ultimately, I want each element to be moved individually using touch

??

Answer (score 0):

You've already picked up your node in the `touchesBegan` example you posted. If you assign your buttons a `name` when you create them, then you can use this to ascertain exactly which SKShapeNode the user has touched and take action accordingly.

E.g. button.name = yourText

Then in `touchedBegan`, you can check to see which button has been touched:

```
if node.name = "testlabel" {
...
}
```

You could also subclass SKShapeNode to create your specialist buttons.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response !
But how can I actually assign a name to an element, created by a function.
That's exactly my problem...

Comment: What do you want to happen when this button is touched? If you've created multiple identical buttons from this function, are they all supposed to do the same thing when touched or different things? If different, how does the user know which button to press? What are the distinguishing features of the different buttons?

Comment: @mtacki See my edit to my answer to see how you could use the `name` property.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to create classes, which contain the function...

```
    class Arzt {


    func createButton(bx: CGFloat, by: CGFloat, bw: CGFloat, bh: CGFloat, yourText: String) {

        let button = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: bx, y: by, width: bw, height: bh), cornerRadius: 5)

        button.fillColor = UIColor.darkGray

        let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"ArialMT")
        label.text = yourText

        button.addChild(label)
        self.addChild(button)

 }   
}
```

I could now create a new instance of Arzt, saying

```
let test = Arzt()
test.createButton(bx: CGFloat(200), by: CGFloat(150), bw: CGFloat(130), bh: CGFloat(30), yourText: "text")
```

I guess by doing this, I could later access the single instances by their name, in this case "test"

Still some error here... 
It's throwing out

**Value of Type "GameScene.Arzt" has no member 'addChild'**

on the last line in the function:

```
self.addChild(button)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must read some tutorial before ask a question here...

add a string like reference

```
func createButton(bx: CGFloat, by: CGFloat, bw: CGFloat, bh: CGFloat, yourText: String, ref: String) {

    let button = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: bx, y: by, width: bw, height: bh), cornerRadius: 5)
    button.fillColor = UIColor.blue
    button.name = ref //here you can reference it
    ( ... )
    self.addChild(button)
    .....
}

if !touchWhere.isEmpty {
            for node in touchWhere {
                if let node = node as? SKShapeNode {
                    switch node.name 
                      case "ref1"
                          ....
                      case "ref2"
                          ....
                }
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

I am actually reading tutorials- but it's so exciting to try out stuff...
I know that I have to learn a lot- still fun to dive into some advanced stuff :-)

Anyways- thanks a bunch !